# Remove keyboard or place Picker View on TOP of keyboard

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

Anyone has any idea how one can achieve the same look as when you press on the "From:" in the Mail iphone app when you have more than one user account.

I'd like to remove my keyboard, but WITHOUT animating it.  Rather just disappear and instead of it have a UIPickerView appear.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since iOS 3.2 you can set the `inputView` property of a `UITextField` to a custom view. This view is then shown instead of the keyboard as input for that view.

There's no way to achieve this before iOS 3.2 I know.

[UITextField Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006888-CH3-SW53)

Comment: Thank you tonklon!!

I'm gonna have to come up with a vanilla version of mine I believe because I want people using 3.1.X to be able to use it too.